# Is my translation of unless into propositional logic correct?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, logic-translation

I have the following sentences:

**I won't go the library unless I need a book**

> *p:* I will go the library
>
> *q:* I need a book

I replaced *unless* with *if not* as follows:

**I won't go the library if I *don't* need a book**

Then: $\lnot q \rightarrow p$ is my translation correct here?

And what if I paraphrased the sentence to the following:

**If I won't go the library then I (don't) need a book.**

$\lnot p \rightarrow \lnot q $

Would it still be correct?

Comment: If $p$ stands for "I will go the library", then "I won't go the library" must be $\lnot p$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"$A$ unless $B$" is [usually read in English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185211/trouble-understanding-the-meaning-of-sentences-with-unless) as

> $A$, if not $B$.

Thus, for **I won't go the library unless I need a book**, will be:

> **I won't go the library, if I do not need a book**.

With:

> $p$: I will go the library
>
> $q$: I need a book

will be:

> > $\lnot q \to \lnot p$

that is the same as:

> $p \to q$.

---

> $\lnot q \to \lnot p$

is not equivalent to:

> $\lnot p \to \lnot q$,

and this is consistent with the fact that:

> **If I won't go the library, then I don't need a book**

is not the same as the previous:

> **I won't go the library, if I do not need a book**.

---

---

Trough the *truth-functional* equivalence between "if $B$, then $A$" and "not $B$ or $A$", we have that :

> "$A$ unless $B$" is equivalent to "$B$ or $A$".

Comment: Let's say I replace _unless_ with _whenever_ in this sentence: "I go the the library whenever I need a book.", so basically the logical translation is: $p \rightarrow q$. Another solution would be: $\lnot p \rightarrow \lnot q$, however, not the same as the original sentence, but still correct. Correct me if I'm wrong? I can see different combinations here, but I can't tell the right one:
***whenever I don't need a book, I don't go to the library* = $\lnot p \rightarrow \lnot q$
*whenever I go the library then I need a book** = $p \rightarrow q$

Comment: @direprobs - YES: "B when A" is "if A, then B". Thus, "I go the the library whenever I need a book", must be "If  I need a book, then I go the the library", i.e. (with $p$ and $q$ as you defined them) again: $p \to q$. Thus, $\lnot p \to \lnot q$ is **not** correct.

Comment: I'm really having hard time trying to translate sentences into logic, consider this: 
**A =“Angelo comes to the party”;**

**B =“Bruno comes to the party”;**

**C =“Carlo comes to the party”.**

“Carlo comes to the party only if Angelo and Bruno do not come”
So, if I write it this way: $(\lnot A \land \lnot B) \rightarrow C$, is it correct?

Comment: @direprobs - Yes, it is. "A only if B" is again: "if A, then B".

Comment: Therefore $(\lnot A \land \lnot B) \rightarrow C$ is the same as $C\rightarrow (\lnot A \land \lnot B)$.

Comment: @direprobs - NO; $p \to q$ and $q \to p$ are not equivalent; check with truth table.

Comment: I get you, $C\rightarrow (\lnot A \land \lnot B)$ is the equivalent of this sentence: "If Carlo comes to the party then Angelo and Bruno do not come” which is the _converse_.

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about your sentence carefully:

> I won't go the library unless I need a book.

This sounds like you hate the library, and that as a general rule of thumb, you should not be expected to be caught dead there, except for one extenuating circumstance (you need a book). Let's evaluate your proposed translations.

> **Translation 1 ($\neg q \to p$):** If I don't need a book, then I'll go to the library.

This definitely doesn't make sense. After all, you hate libraries. And you don't even need a book!

> **Translation 2 ($\neg p \to \neg q$):** If I won't go to the library, then I don't need a book.

This isn't quite as bad of a translation, but it doesn't necessarily follow from the original sentence. Perhaps the library is merely your last resort for getting a book, and so it's possible that there are other alternatives (like borrowing your friend's old copy, for example). Thus, you are able to successfully avoid a trip to the dreaded library and yet simultaneously satisfy your need for a book.

> **Correct Translation ($p \to q$):** If I go to the library, then I need a book.

This works. There are only three possible combinations and one impossible combination:

- **Possible #1:** You are not at the library and you don't need a book. (*happens all the time*)
- **Possible #2:** You are not at the library and you need a book. (*hopefully there are alternatives*)
- **Possible #3:** You are at the library and you need a book. (*rarely happens, but you had no other choice*)
- **Impossible:** You are at the library and you don't need a book. (*...then why are you there?*)

Comment: Is it okay if I change the order of the sentence? "I play football when I am bored". _p:_ I play football; _q:_ I am bored. So basically: $p \rightarrow q$. What about: $\lnot p \rightarrow \lnot q$ or $q \rightarrow p$ ? I suspect the first one $\lnot p \rightarrow \lnot q$ is wrong, because I might not be bored but still play football!